# Get the index of elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing, each

Let say I have this

```
<ul class='list'>
  <li>item0</li>
  <li class='active'>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li class='active'>item3</li>
  <li class='active'>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
  <li>item6</li>
</ul>

<ul class='list'>
  <li class='active'>item0</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li class='active'>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li class='active'>item5</li>
  <li class='active'>item6</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to display their current index ex.(134,0256), but it displays (0123456). I tried some codes but it only display the selected index.

How can I do that?

thanks.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $( "ul.list li.active" ).each(function(index) {
                console.log(index);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in the [callback](http://api.jquery.com/each/) would be the index in the jQuery object collection. To get index relative to its siblings use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $("ul.list li.active").each(function(index) {
      console.log($(this).index()); // get index within its parent
    });
  });
});
```

```js
$("ul.list li.active").each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list'>
  <li>item0</li>
  <li class='active'>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li class='active'>item3</li>
  <li class='active'>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
  <li>item6</li>
</ul>

<ul class='list'>
  <li class='active'>item0</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li class='active'>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li class='active'>item5</li>
  <li class='active'>item6</li>
</ul>
```

---

For separating each list with a comma use additional iterator for the list, it's easy to do with jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method.

```
console.log(
  $("ul.list").map(function() { // iterate over each list
    return $("li.active", this).map(function() { // iterate over children li
      return $(this).index(); // return the index
    }).get().join(''); // get the result as array and join the values
  }).get().join() // get the result as array and join the values with comma
)
```

```js
console.log(
  $("ul.list").map(function() {
    return $("li.active", this).map(function() {
      return $(this).index();
    }).get().join('');
  }).get().join()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list'>
  <li>item0</li>
  <li class='active'>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li class='active'>item3</li>
  <li class='active'>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
  <li>item6</li>
</ul>

<ul class='list'>
  <li class='active'>item0</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li class='active'>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li class='active'>item5</li>
  <li class='active'>item6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so its the $this, sir how to separate the ul with comma?

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla for that you need to use separate iteration..... I will add as an another answer

Answer (score 1):

Your selection will find all the elemnts in selection. Instead you want to find elements inside other element separately. Which I believe is only possible by searching. So your code should look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(){
        var indexes = [];
        $( "ul.list").each(function() {
            $("li", this).each(function(index) {
                 if($(this).hasClass('active') {
                     indexes.push(index);
                 }
            });
        });
        console.log(indexes);
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome @MarkGerrylMirandilla!!